# Connection Refused error when Mongo is connected to application

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mocha.js, body-parser

I am writing some tests in Mocha and my first test always passes:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

describe('The express app', () => {
  it('handles a GET request to /api', done => {
    request(app)
      .get('/api')
      .end((err, response) => {
        assert(response.body.hi === 'there');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

But this second test always fails since its inception:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const request = require("supertest");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = require("../../app");

const Driver = mongoose.model("driver");

describe("Drivers controller", () => {
  it("Post to /api/drivers create a new driver", () => {
    let oldCount;
    return Driver.count()
      .then(count => {
        oldCount = count;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request(app)
            .post("api/drivers")
            .send({ email: "test@test.com" })
            .end((err, res) => {
              if (err) {
                reject(err);
              } else {
                resolve(res);
              }
            });
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return Driver.count();
      })
      .then(newCount => {
        assert(oldCount + 1 === newCount);
      });
  });
});
```

The above is the third refactor of it and I am testing this controller:

```
const Driver = require("../models/driver");

module.exports = {
  greeting(req, res) {
    res.send({ hi: "there" });
  },

  create(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    const driverProps = req.body;

    Driver.create(driverProps).then(driver => res.send(driver));
  }
};
```

With the original refactor I was getting that the `assert(oldCount + 1 === newCount);` was returning `falsy` instead of `truthy` which was not expected and with the refactor of my test I get a connection refused, but the db is connected I checked with this configuration:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./routes/routes");
const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/muber", { useMongoClient: true });

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on("connected", function() {
  console.log("connected to db");
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
routes(app);

module.exports = app;
```

results in:

> [nodemon] starting `mocha --recursive -R min`   connected to db
>
> 1 passing (43ms)   1 failing
>
> 1) Drivers controller Post to /api/drivers create a new driver:
>        Error: ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
>         at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:13)
>         at Server.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
>         at emitCloseNT (net.js:1600:8)
>         at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
>
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy cow, I had to stop the test and stop the mongo database server and restart it then run the test and everything is passing and working as expected:

```
  connected to db
{ email: 'test@test.com' }

  2 passing (132ms)

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

The refactor was actually not necessary but I did tweak it a bit when I put it back to:

```
describe("Drivers controller", () => {
  it("Post to /api/drivers create a new driver", done => {
    Driver.count().then(count => {
      request(app)
        .post("/api/drivers")
        .send({ email: "test@test.com" })
        .set("Accept", "application/json")
        .expect("Content-Type", /json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(() => {
          Driver.count().then(newCount => {
            assert(count + 1 === newCount);
            done();
          });
        });
    });
  });
});
```